# Where can I find the Windows header files

Tags: winapi

Sometimes in my research into Microsoft functions, I'll see the name of a constant and perhaps a reference to a header file - like winuser.h. I don't often need to refer to them but when I do, I wind up spending some time Googling to find out where those files are. With this question, I can hopefully come to the answer right away. The question, as the title says, is: Assuming I've installed Visual Studio or the SDK, where in the file directory structure on a windows machine can I find the basic windows header files, like windows.h and winuser.h?

Comment: There's no preset location.  These files are not included with a base Windows installation.  Their location depends on where you have installed Visual Studio, or the Windows API.

Comment: In my installs, the headers wound up in the same C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\vX.X\Include location.

Comment: In a typical case, you don't really need to care about the location. When you want to look at the contents, type `#include <windows.h>` (or whatever) into your editor, then right click and select "open document <windows.h>`. If your editor doesn't support that, switch to one that does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to install Visual Studio or the Windows SDK. I'd give URLs here but they change with every new version of windows. The header files could be in

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\vX.X\Include
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\vX.X\Include

  (where vX.X reflects the version number)

**Update - May 2020**
I'm on a new machine and installed VS2019 and the WindowsSDK and here are the new locations:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
  Studio\2019\Professional\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\vc15\SDK\include\um
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um

I do not see any includes in the 'Program Files' folders.

Comment: Well, yes, technically you could just install the Windows API.  But the way that 95 percent of Windows developers get the Windows API onto their computers is to install Visual Studio.

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot to mention Visual Studio loads those files as well - and to the same folder - thanks!

Comment: That location hasn't been used in years, at least not when running a 64-bit OS (which apparently you aren't).

Comment: hmm - actually, I am using 64 bit - but it's Win7 - does that make a difference?

Comment: I think I see what you may be referring to - the header files are also in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\vX.X\Include

Comment: The *"Microsoft SDKs"* folder isn't used for any recent SDK (Windows 8 and later). That SDK installs into a *"Windows Kits"* folder, and the layout is different, too. There's an additional version selector underneath the *"Include"* directory.